# Why i cannot select first choice of the spinner?

Tags: android, list, drop-down-menu, spinner, default

I created a spinner in which the first selection appears as default. But if i click on this it doesn't work.

```
protected boolean inhibit_spinner = true;

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    if (inhibit_spinner) {
        inhibit_spinner = false;
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Selection.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("selection", item);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

If i click on spinner and select any other choice it thrown activity, but if i click on it and choose the default value (the first choice) it doesn't thrown the activity. Why?

Answer (score 2):

onItemSelected function will be called only when the user selects a different item in spinner than the currently selected item.

For example :

If your spinner items are item1,item2,item3 and item4.

- Select item4 , Then onItemSelected function will be called with position as 3.
- Select item4 again , But this time onItemSelected function won't be called.
- Select item0 , Then onItemSelected function will be called with position as 0.
- Select item0 again , But this time onItemSelected function won't be called.

I believe you need to change the application flow a bit. Instead of going to next activity on selection of spinner item, provide a button to the user. User can select the option he wants using the spinner. When he clicks on the button , get the currently selected item from spinner using the function "spinner.getSelectedItem()" and pass it to the next activity.

Please let me know If this doesnt solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default the first option is selected (position 0). So the **onItemSelected** isn't called because the position hasn't been changed.

Try to add an element like 'Select one' as a first option to avoid this behavior.